# Fetch Elastic API with query Javascript

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, fetch-api

i have elastic API and i try to fetch it with javascript and query on the fetch, but i don't know where to place the query, i only know how to fetch it just with authorization, can we fetch the elastic api with query ?

The Elastic Query:

```
GET http://192.168.150.155:9900/em-employeedata/_search
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

The Javascript Code:

```
var url = 'http://192.168.150.155:9900/em-employeedata/_search/';

async function getapi(url) {

const response = await fetch(url, {method:'GET', 
headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('em_user:3md@t@2o22')}})

var data = await response.json();

}

getapi(url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Elasticsearch [Javascript client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html) for same.

You can check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/search_examples.html) documentation where they have given example of Search.

Below is sample example:

```js
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const client = new Client({
  cloud: { id: '<cloud-id>' },
  auth: { apiKey: 'base64EncodedKey' }
})

const result = await client.search({
    index: 'game-of-thrones',
    query: {
      match: {
        quote: 'winter'
      }
    }
  })

  console.log(result.hits.hits)
```

Above example show connecting using `cloud_id` and `apiKey` but there are other options also available. Please check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/7.17/client-connecting.html) link.

Comment: can i use it without node js? because i don't use node js, i use a front end javascript

Comment: If you are not using node.js then you can simply set fetch method to `POST` and pass `body` with json request.